# Keyboard is not responsive inside of Tor's firefox

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox, vidalia

When running Tor via the Tor Browser Bundle, Vidalia works fine, Tor runs and connected, Firefox runs and connects to https://check.torproject.org which tells me that I have Tor enabled with an IP address from Germany or something, but there's just one thing.

**The keyboard doesn't work!**

I can't use the keyboard at all, not in inputs, not in the browser bar, not with keyboard shortcuts, nothing.

I use Ubuntu 13.10 x64, I `chown` all the files in the directory.

Comment: This is a known bug: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/9353

Comment: @bastik: I seriously doubt that everyone who has Tor on a 64 bit system gets that though, can't I do anything to solve it? (I tried uninstalling ibus btw and it didn't work)

Comment: Others wrote that stopping the process from running helped, I don't know. It seems that this is more a support question. https://www.torproject.org/about/contact.html.en#support There are a bunch of people and they might know what works best. This Q&A might not be suited for solving this problem. Well maybe if there's an easy answer. Overall I hope this will be fixed 'soon' and render your question obsolete.

Comment: @ Madara Uchihia the 'AT' part gets stripped out over and over again

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I have the same problem (I'm running 13.10, 64 bit). Also, clicking on start-tor-browser doesn't work even though nautilus has the executable box checked. It brings up gedit instead. The only way to make it run is to open a terminal and execute the command that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a known bug on ibus-x11 on Ubuntu 13.10 amd64

According to the [open Trac ticket](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/9353) you should `killall ibus-x11`

Comment: The last workaround in the ticket with `export GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"` does not work for you? `killal ibus-x11` is rather brutal.

Comment: yep, this solution worked for me: http://askubuntu.com/a/377321/62483

Answer (score -2):

open ubuntu software center, search ibus, then uninstall.

Comment: Can you clarify how this would fix the problem?